# Python3 string variable keeps messing my urllib.request

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, beautifulsoup

I'm using a for loop to crawl through some directories of a site.

```
for url in URL_list:

    for paged in range(1,99):
        fullURL=("%s/?count=96&paged=%s&p=&page_id="%(url,paged))

        print(fullURL)
        source= urllib.request.urlopen(fullURL)
```

I'm getting an error `http.client.BadStatusLine: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">`

I'm pretty sure that the problem occurs due to the `fullURL` string variable because it is printed as `http://www.somesite.com/category/new-items
/?count=96&paged=1&p=&page_id=`

**EDIT 1**
Looks like the "url" variable from the list is stored with spaces.

Comment: What about the `page_id`? It should be specified as well, right? But it's not in your example.

Comment: @Highstaker It seems that it doesn't matter. The problem isn't in the url but on how it is stored and printed. The directory of the url is in the next line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've managed to fix it with the following code. Hope that it will help someone in the future.

```
for url in URL_list:
       for paged in range(1,99):
            URLDirectory="/?count=96&paged=%s&p=&page_id="%paged
            fullURL=url+directoryURL
            fullURL=''.join(fullURL.split())
```